# Feature comparison between extended and included Azure pipeline template

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am currently writing a project internal guideline for the development of Azure pipelines. After trying out more and more things with templates I am really wondering what the feature differences are between an extended pipeline template and one that is just included via "template" statement.

What I know is that in an included template no resources can be specified and acc to the MS docs a "required template approval" can only be specified for extended templates (if my understanding is correct). Apart from that (and a little bit of variable handling) I have the feeling there is no difference at all.

If my knowledge is incomplete or wrong please give me a hint what is wrong and where I can get the missing information.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another difference is that the included template can be used with steps in the pipeline, while external template cannot.

Here is an example:

The following script is right:

```
steps:
- script: npm install
- template: resource-template.yml
```

The following is wrong:

```
extends:
  template: resource-template.yml

steps:
- script: npm install
```